# how to limit an text field to a certain amount of letters?

Tags: javascript, html, input, field

I have a text field on my website that i wnt to limit my users from writing more than 2 letters in.

```
<label>Text</label>
<input type='text' id='changeText' name='changeText'>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='text' id='changeText' name='changeText' maxlength="2">
```

Use the max length attribute